# Baseball games alphametic

Tags: no-computers, alphametic

Every letter a decimal digit, different letters for different digits:

```
    BASE
  + BALL
 --------
   GAMES
```

Which digit does each letter represent?

Comment: I saw a similar puzzle like this: send + more = money. The g has to be more than or equal to one.

Comment: this whole thing seems to originate from: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-cryptarithmetic-problems-like-BASE+BALL-GAMES and the answer is probably copied from there aswell, quite similar.... suspicious

Comment: @Daedric more than? It *has* to be 1

Comment: I changed it for some reason, it originally said equal to one, I had a mental break down and changed my mind lol.

Comment: @Daedric my answer starts similarly to that one, but I considered possible values for A while they tried values for SE and B.

Comment: @f'' your clearly a reliable source, I trust you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming numbers can't start with 0, `G` is 1 because two four-digit numbers can't sum to 20000 or more.

`SE`+`LL`=`ES` or `1ES`.

If it is `ES`, then `LL` must be a multiple of 9 because `SE` and `ES` are always congruent mod 9. But `LL` is a multiple of 11, so it would have to be 99, which is impossible.

So `SE`+`LL`=`1ES`. `LL` must be congruent to 100 mod 9. The only multiple of 11 that works is 55, so `L` is 5.

`SE`+55=`1ES`. This is possible when `E`+5=`S`. The possibilities for `ES` are 27, 38, or 49.

`BA`+`BA`+1=`1AM`. `B` must be at least 5 because `B`+`B` (possibly +1 from a carry) is at least 10.

If `A` is less than 5, then `A`+`A`+1 does not carry, and `A` must be even. Inversely, if `A` is greater than 5, it must be odd. The possibilities for `A` are 0, 2, 4, 7, or 9.

- 0 does not work because `M` would have to be 1.
- 2 and 7 don't work because `M` would have to be 5.
- 9 doesn't work because `M` would also have to be 9.

So `A` is 4, `M` is 9, and `B` is 7. This leaves `38` as the only possibility for `ES`. The full equation is:

```
    7483
  + 7455
 --------
   14938
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer I got by just fiddling with numbers.

Answer (score 5):

There are in total three solutions (with unique numbers):

```
G A M E S B L
-------------
0 4 9 1 6 2 5
0 4 9 3 8 2 5
1 4 9 3 8 7 5
```

So apart from the solution in @f''s answer, we have

```
  2483
+ 2455
--------
 04938
```

and

```
  2461
+ 2455
--------
 04916
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer by looking at the lowest numbers:

```
E + L must equal S or 10 + S

S + L must equal E or 10 + E
```

I set L to zero which means that there won't be a one to carry.  This allows me to set E = S ("es", not "five").  Let's pick a number:

```
E = 5
S = E = 5
L = 0
```

This gives:

```
  BA55
+ BA00
------
 GAM55
```

Let's pick a number for A.  This also gives us M.  Note that if 2*A is < 10, A has to be even because it equals 2B - 10.  If instead 2*A >= 10, the one carries over and A has to be odd because 2B + 1 - 10 has to equal A.

```
A = 2
M = 4
```

This gives:

```
  B255
+ B200
------
 G2455
```

Now I see that B + B has to equal 12.  B = 6:

```
  6255
+ 6200
------
 12455
```

Using this method, I also found these results:

```
B = 7, A = 5, S = 5, L = 0, G = 1, E = 5, and M = 0
B = 8, A = 7, S = 1, L = 0, G = 1, E = 1, and M = 4
```

This method won't give every result because I'm assuming that L is always zero.

Comment: It does say "different letters for different digits", which I'm taking to mean that E is not equal to S as you have here.